# How can I get my textboxes to be closer to my labels?

Tags: html, css, margins

```css
.intro h1 {
  font-family: 'Cambria';
  font-size: 16pt;
  font: bold;
  text-align: left;
}

.intro p {
  font-family: 'Calibri';
  font: italic;
  font-size: 12pt;
  padding: 0px 690px 0px 20px;
  text-align: left;
}

.content {
  border: 2px solid;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#para1 {
  padding: 0px 1050px 0px 20px;
}

#para2 {
  padding: 0px 1099px 0px 20px;
}

.username-label,
.username-textbox,
.password-label,
.password-textbox {
 margin: 10px 0px 0px 300px;
 position: relative; 
 top: -70px; 
}

#button1{ 
     background-color: #add8e6;
     margin:0px 0px 20px 370px; 
     width: 100px;
     position: relative; 
     top: -70px; 
}

#button2{
  background-color: #add8e6;
}


.Username-label1, 
.Password-label2,           
.Email-label3, 
.Repeat-Email-label4, 
.username-new-input-textbox, 
.password-new-input-textbox, 
.email-new-input-textbox, 
.reenter-new-input-textbox
{
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 350px;
  position: relative; 
  top: -20px; 
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <link href="Home.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <title>Project</title>

</head>

<body>
  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="~/Scripts/Home.js"></script>



<div class="container">
  <div class="intro">

    <h1>Welcome to Cuyahoga Community College Student Services Online</h1>

    <p>Cuyahoga Community College recognizes students' rights to access personal and academic records in accordance with the Family Educational Rights and Privacy Act of 1974 (FERPA) as amended by Public Law 93-568.</p>
  </div>
  <br/>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="row top">
      <p id="para1">Already have an account with us? Returning users may log in by entering their site username and password. </p>
      <div id="login">
        <label class="username-label">
         <span>Username</span> &nbsp;
         <input class="existing username-input-textbox" type="text" value="" />
          </label>
        <br/><br/>
        <label class="password-label">
        <span>Password</span> &nbsp;
        <input class="existing password-input-textbox" type="password" value="" />
         </label>
        <br/><br/>
        <button id="button1">Log in</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div class="row bottom">
      <p id="para2">New users, please create a new account by providing us with some basic information.</p>
      <div class= "new_customers_info">
        <label class="Username-label1">
        <span>Username</span>
        <input class="username-new-input-textbox" type="text" value="" />
         </label>
         <br/><br/>

        <label class="Password-label2">
        <span>Password</span> 
        <input class="password-new-input-textbox" type="password" value="" />
         </label>
         <br/><br/>

        <label class="Email-label3">
         <span>Email</span> 
         <input class="email-new-input-textbox" type="text" value=""/>
          </label>
          <br/><br/>

        <label class="Repeat-Email-label4">
        <span>Repeat Email Address</span> 
         <input class="reenter-new-input-textbox" type="text" value="" />
         </label>
         <br/><br/>

        <button id="button2">Create Account</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
   <br/><br/>
  <footer>Cuyahoga Community College</footer>
  <footer>700 Carnegie Avenue, Cleveland, Ohio, 44115</footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to figure out how can I get my textboxes to be closer to my labels. How can I achieve this using CSS? I tried messing around with margin left positioning but that just moves the elements further to the right. Any suggestions? Here is my code.

Comment: You can use `margin-left: - px` a negative number or `position: relative`and then move it with left, right, top, bottom. Also you could use bootstrap or other css framework.

Comment: @ Ellebkey I tried to use -px with the margin left, but that does not help.

Comment: @Ellebkey I figured it! I can take the input textboxes class selector tags out of the css positioning of the labels and place the input textboxes classes into something separate. That way I can control just the input textboxes and not the labels too.

Comment: well done, I keep my recomendation to use a css framework, that way you save a lot of time, but with this situation your learn more how it works css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have labels and input together. But if you put input with margin it will move them even further. It should be more like this:

```
.Username-label1, 
.Password-label2,           
.Email-label3, 
.Repeat-Email-label4
{
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 350px;
  position: relative; 
  top: -20px; 
}
.username-new-input-textbox, 
.password-new-input-textbox,
.email-new-input-textbox,
.reenter-new-input-textbox
{
position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `input` and `span` tags both have a style of `display: inline-block`. The `inline-block` rule actually takes into account the spacing in your HTML. A couple ways you can deal with this is to either put your elements on the same line, put a comment between your HTML elements to fill up the space, or add a CSS rule to account for the spacing in your html file.

## HTML Fixes

### Keep Code On The Same Line

```
<span>Your Label Text</span><input type="text" value="Your Input Text" />
```

or

### Place Comments Between The Elements

Note: *(`<!--This is a comment in HTML-->`)*

```
    <span>Your Label Text</span><!--
 --><input type="text" value="Your Input Text" />
```

## CSS Fix

```
input {
    margin-left: -2px;
}
```

**Side Note**:
The structure of your html is currently:

```
<label class="password-label">
    <span>Password</span> &nbsp;
    <input class="existing password-input-textbox" type="password" value="" />
 </label>
```

but it should be this instead:

```
<label class="password-label" for="passwordId">Password</label>
<input id="passwordId" class="existing password-input-textbox" type="password" value="" />
```

The `span` tag was removed since you weren't adding any kind of style to it specifically and the `input` element was removed from the `label` tag so you could take advantage of the label's `for` attribute which will link your `label` to your `input` by the input's `id` attribute value. Now that the `for` tag is linked to the `input` tag, if you click on the label it will put focus into your input field. Also, the notice the removal of the no-break space entity (`&nbsp;`).

Comment: @SupposedlySam-Should I remove the other span tags from the other labels as well?

Comment: Yes. Always try to keep your code consistent so you don't have to figure out how you did it in each place. The `label` and `input` tags have a style of `display: inline-block` on them by default anyway so you should be fine. Just remember to bring your `input` tag out from inside your `label` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the left margin to a negative number?

Comment: @ j3tb1ack I tried but the takes the elements out of the border.